# Cartesian Product sets complements proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

English isn't my first language, so my apologies for any mistakes.
I have to prove this:

$(A\setminus B) \times C = (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C)$

One direction:

$(x,y) \in (A\setminus B) \times C $

$\Rightarrow x \in (A\setminus B) \land y \in C $

$\Rightarrow  x \in A \land x \not \in B \land y \in C$

$ \Rightarrow  x \in A \land x \not \in B \land y \in C \land y \in C$

(now just rearrange)

$ \Rightarrow  x \in A \land y \in C \land x \not \in B \land y \in C$

$ \Rightarrow  (x,y) \in (A \times C) \land (x,y) \not \in (B \times C)$

$ \Rightarrow  (x,y) \in (A \times C) \setminus  (B \times C)$

Now comes the problem for the other direction:

$(x,y) \in (A \times C) \setminus  (B \times C)$

$\Rightarrow  (x,y) \in (A \times C) \land (x,y) \not \in (B \times C)$

$\Rightarrow  x \in A \land y \in C \land (x \not \in B \lor y \not \in C)$

$\Rightarrow  x \in A \land (y \in C \land x \not \in B) \lor (y \in C \land y \not \in C) $

This is a contradiction. So how do I transform $(x,y) \not \in (B \times C)$ properly. Because I could just copy it from the first part.

But these scenarios could be possible: 
$x \not \in B, y \not \in C$ or both at the same time.

My thought was that from the first part of the statement $(x,y) \in (A \times C) \setminus  (B \times C)$ we already know that $y \in C$, so in the second part we can say that the case $y \not \in C$ can't apply.

Is this correct?
It was the only explanation I could come up with to make this proof work.

Comment: I formatted everything using MathJax. Please take a look so you know how to do this for next time

Comment: @Bram28 Thank a lot

Comment: Sure thing!  Welcome to M.SE! :)

Comment: But if $(x,y) \in (A\times C)\setminus (B\times C)$ then $(x,y)\in A\times C$ so $y\in C$.  But $(x,y)\not \in B\times C$ so either $x \not \in B$ or $x\not \in C$.  But $y$ *IS* in $C$.  So $x \not \in B$.

Comment: Remember that $A \lor FALSE \equiv A$.  So $\Rightarrow  x \in A \land [(y \in C \land x \not \in B) \lor (y \in C \land y \not \in C)] \equiv A\land (y \in C \land x \not \in B) $.

Comment: "we already know that y∈C, so in the second part we can say that the case y∉C

can't apply.

Is this correct?"  Of course it is correct!  Of course you can apply it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a little correction:

Because of the mix of $\land$ and $\lor$, you should avoid any confusion by adding another pair of parentheses, e.g:

$x \in A \land \color{red}[(y \in C \land x \not \in B) \lor (y \in C \land y \not \in C) \color{red}]$

Now, as you say, $(y \in C \land y \not \in C)$ cannot be the case, and so we can ignore it.

Formally, you can do that like this:

$x \in A \land [(y \in C \land x \not \in B) \lor (y \in C \land y \not \in C)] $

$\Rightarrow  x \in A \land [(y \in C \land x \not \in B) \lor \bot ]$ (the $\bot$ is the logic symbol for contradiction)

$\Rightarrow  x \in A \land (y \in C \land x \not \in B)$

and you can finish it from there